# How add many metadata

Tags: nft, mint

I want mint nft with many metadata?

https://meshjs.dev/apis/transaction/minting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example from the page you referenced, but with additional metadata fields attached. You can create your own custom metadata fields on the asset this way.

```
const assetMetadata: AssetMetadata = {
  "name": "Mesh Token",
  "image": "ipfs://QmRzicpReutwCkM6aotuKjErFCUD213DpwPq6ByuzMJaua",
  "mediaType": "image/jpg",
  "description": "This NFT is minted by Mesh (https://meshjs.dev/).",
  "custom1": "Your custom value 1",
  "custom2": "Your custom value 2"
};
const asset: Mint = {
  assetName: 'MeshToken',
  assetQuantity: '1',
  metadata: assetMetadata,
  label: '721',
  recipient: 'addr_test1vpvx0sacufuypa2k4sngk7q40zc5c4npl337uusdh64kv0c7e4cxr' 
};
tx.mintAsset(
  forgingScript,
  asset,
);
```